# What is equivalent to 'as table of' in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a following query in Oracle that I need to convert to SQL Server

Oracle:

```
create or replace
TYPE "PARAMS" as table of varchar2(3000)
```

I am unsure how to convert 'as table of' object to SQL Server.

Comment: You'd be better of explaining what it does. And then check the docs for [`CREATE TYPE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-type-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). But I suspect it isn't possible, if its creating a type based on an existing table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's Oracle's way of creating user defined table types.
In T-SQL it would look like this:

```sql
CREATE TYPE Params AS TABLE
(
    [value] Nvarchar(3000) 
)
```

Comment: I tried doing it .. It give error for line 'Nvarchar(3000)'  saying  - The definition for column 'Nvarchar' must include a data type

Comment: Chang - please check the documentation.

Comment: @Chang you need a column name

Comment: `value` is a reserved word.

Comment: @gvee Only reserved in ODBC, not in TSQL. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: The query when used in Oracle does not have the [value] parameter. It works fine in Oracle though. It seems for MS SQL value is must. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Chang yes because SQL Server works differently - you need to define the columns rather than gesture at some table over there